# Gmail API set up with service account and not O Auth Client ID

Tags: java, google-api, gmail, google-oauth, gmail-api

I've noticed that Google Storage uses something along the lines of creating credentials to get the service started. What is the Gmail equivalent? I do not want to make an O Auth Client Id. I have attached below the Gmail Quick Start Guide which uses O Auth Client ID.

I have also tried looking through the documentation but I cannot find anything outside of O Auth Client ID. If anyone can point me in the right direction I am trying to build a more secure app using service account.

```
Credentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_PATH));
            this.storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials)
                    .build().getService();
```

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.GmailScopes;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Label;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.ListLabelsResponse;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class GmailQuickstart {
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Gmail API Java Quickstart";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS);
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
     * @return An authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
     */
    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = GmailQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();

        // Print the labels in the user's account.
        String user = "me";
        ListLabelsResponse listResponse = service.users().labels().list(user).execute();
        List<Label> labels = listResponse.getLabels();
        if (labels.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No labels found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Labels:");
            for (Label label : labels) {
                System.out.printf("- %s\n", label.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the service account credentials, you will have to adapt your code in order to use them, similar to:

```
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID = "SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID";
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Gmail API Java Quickstart";

PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey)keystore.getKey(KEY.toCharArray()); 

HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

GoogleCredential credentials = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(key)
                .setServiceAccountEmail("SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID")
                .build();

Gmail service =  new Gmail.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credentials)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
```

However, bear in mind that creating a service account is *not enough* - you will also have to delegate the authority by impersonating another user in your domain.

As for documentation, this extensive guide [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#java) might be of help to your use-case.

#### Reference

- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#java);
- [OAuth Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client).

Comment: What would be the non deprecated alternative to GoogleCredential?